# my django server's import_export module don't work especialy in importing

Tags: django, django-import-export

```
'''class institutionResource(resources.ModelResource):


       class Meta:
           model = institution
           exclude = ('id',)
           import_id_fields = ('institution_number',)'''


'''class institutionAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['institution_number', 'quiz1','quiz2','quiz3']
        resource_class=institutionResource
        pass'''
```

this is my code but when i import my xlsx file, look like this picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ohZG.png)

this is my model code

```
enter code here


'''class institution(models.Model):
       institution_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, primary_key=True)
       quiz1 = models.CharField(max_length=400,blank=True, default=False)
       quiz2= models.CharField(max_length=400,blank=True, default=False)
       quiz3 = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, default=False)
       qrcode=models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False)
       latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       class Meta:
            ordering = ['institution_number']
'''
```

Comment: plz help me! ..

Comment: Read [this page](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#declaring-fields) in the docs.  Make sure that the `column_name` property matches the declared column name in the import file (case is important)

Comment: thanks for your help it works!